# Can linum-relative disregard folding?

Tags: linum-mode

Is it possible to have `linum-relative` disregard folding?  The default works poorly with evil `<count>j/k`-jumping and ex-commands such as `-13t.` in org mode.

(To comments: I said 'screen lines' but that's not what I meant. Sorry.)

Comment: Does it make sense to do so? If your screen is 80 characters wide and your lines are 300 characters long, and you are currently on column 200 (so about half way across the screen on the third `screen line`) and you go up a line are you wanting to stay on the same line but move to column 120 or do you want to stay on column 200 and be on the previous line?

Comment: I presume this is for use in conjunction with `line-move-visual` set non-`nil`, in which case regular movement commands *will* move between visual lines rather than real lines. I think Toothrot wishes to extend that behaviour to line numbering and goto-line commands such that they too will deal in visual lines rather than real lines.

Comment: I suspect numbering visual lines for a large buffer could prove to be pretty slow. Keep in mind that, despite wanting relative numbers, it can only be constrained to processing the *visible* portion of the buffer when you only have a single window on the buffer. The worst-case is still processing the entire buffer, as you may have windows on both the beginning and the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wanted is achieved by

```
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'visual)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
```

And all this time I've been stuck with avy in org mode.